# How to connect Java application to X11 to move cursor

Tags: java

I am trying to write an application like htop or saidar where the application does not keep redrawing the output in the terminal.

I would like to use X11 to move the cursor to where I want it and update the information.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Htop and saidar use Curses (not X11) to position the cursor.

For that you need a curses java library--google told me there was one here http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/

Curses lets you output ASCII characters to move the cursor around the screen.  It can be used over telnet since it's all ASCII